# Product and summation with 3d and 1d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given a 3d array **`X`** with dimensions (`K,n,m`) that can be considered as a stack of `K` (`n,m`) matrices and a 1d vector **`b`** (dim `n`), the goal is to obtain the resulting vector **`r`** (dim `n`) each component of which is calculated as:
[image]

It is easy to see that the expression under the `k`-summation (i.e. two internal sums) is just a dot product **`X_k b X_k`** (and, therefore, can easily be calculated using `numpy`). So, the desired vector **`r`** is

[image]

where **`X_k`** is the `k`-th 2d (`n,m`) 'layer' of 3d array `X`.

I.e. the current solution is

```
r = 0
for k in range(K):
    r += x[k,:,:] @ (b @ x[k, :, :])
```

Can **`r`** be efficiently calculated avoiding a for-loop by `k`?
Or maybe there is another efficient way to calculate **`r`**?

(I tried `np.tensordot` but since it is just pure summation by `k` I didn't get a correct result yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect usecase for [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```py
r = np.einsum('kij,l,klj->i', x, b, x)
```

which will vectorize the operation, e.g. it's more optimal than a for loop.